# Log4net config for propper rolling filenames

Tags: c#, log4net-configuration

My C# config for log4net is

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Logs\" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.txt'" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

and I have this list of log files

[image]

but I want this filename's format

[image]

whats wrong with my config?

Comment: When I copied your shared configuration into one of my applications that uses log4net extensively, it worked exactly like you seem to want.  The only thing I changed from your config is I reduced the roll size to 15 kb so that it would roll more frequently.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont insert `.txt` with  `datePattern` which is `<datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy" />` then `log4net` append `txt.1` and so on with the file name.

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Logs\" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}  - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: +1 Yes it works. If you dont put `.txt` with `datepattern` `log4net` insert `.txt.1` and so on with the file names.

Comment: With this config I have the same issue (